# Read and write values in Firebase Database problem

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read 2 values from Firebase (if exist as in first user there are not) and if needed to update them. Actually i m trying at first to do it with one value, with no luck. My code is

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                final String uid = Objects.requireNonNull( mAuth.getCurrentUser() ).getUid();
                mScoreReference.child( uid ).addListenerForSingleValueEvent( new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        User oldscore = dataSnapshot.getValue( User.class );
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            if(oldscore.getScore()==null){
                                oldscore.setScore(String.valueOf( 0));
                                String oldscorevalue = Objects.requireNonNull(oldscore).getScore();
                                int convertedscore = Integer.parseInt(oldscorevalue);
                                if (convertedscore > 0) {
                                    //Upload points to Database
                                    mScoreReference.child(uid).child( "Score" )
                                            .setValue( convertedscore + newScore );

                                } else mScoreReference.child(uid).child( "Score" ).setValue( newScore );

                            }

                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }


                } );
```

I managed to convert null(the first value as score is not exist) and to set score. So my problem is why i cant update the value, and how can i update 2 values at the same time? Probably i have to use Transaction, but i m not familiar at all with this. I m reading, but i cant find how to convert this code to Transaction.

**UPDATE**

I tried with Transaction.

```
mScoreReference.child( uid ).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                        User user = mutableData.getValue(User.class);
                        if (user.getScore() == null) {
                            mScoreReference.child(uid).child( "Score" ).setValue( newScore );
                        }
                        else{
                            String oldscorevalue = Objects.requireNonNull(user).getScore();
                            int convertedscore = Integer.parseInt(oldscorevalue);
                            mScoreReference.child(uid).child( "Score" )
                                    .setValue( convertedscore + newScore );
                        }

                        // Set value and report transaction success
                        mutableData.setValue(user);
                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                                           DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        // Transaction completed
                        Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
                    }
                });
```

and i have strange results. At first time do nothing, then adds Score and another irelavent User value, and after this adds 2 Score fields in Database.

Comment: Look into using a transaction.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

Comment: @DougStevenson  I m checking it but i find it more difficult to undersand. Thank you for the help.